# Tortoise SVN logging without committing

Tags: svn, logging, tortoisesvn

I normally make multiple small edits to my source code, but I don't want to commit just yet, since the changes are rather trivial. The current method I'm using right now is to log the changes in a text file, then copying the contents into the log when committing.

Is it possible when using Tortoise SVN (or any other SVN tool) to attach log messages to the copy I'm currently working on as I'm editing, then when committing, the log messages are automatically attached to the commit, so I don't have to remember all the changes I've made so far?

Comment: Interesting question. I don't think this is possible. There might be a workaround using meta-properties and a pre-commit hook that turns them into commit messages, though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do a commit and it fails, tortoiseSVN stores the commit message for you to bring it up when you retry. Find that file and append to it would be my suggestion.

vanilla svn is commit.tmp, that's probably a good starting place to look.

EDIT:

EDIT EDIT: You're using tortoise which implies windows. So, you'll probably need something that works on windows. I've quickly rewritten it in python since I suck at cmd scripting

Alternatively, create a directory called logs, store all your notes in there and then do something like this for a commit script

```
for i in `ls logs`; do
    echo -n "$i: "
    cat logs/$i >> commitFile
done
svn commit -F commitFile
```

Or in python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
dirlisting = os.listdir('logs')
commitFile = open("commitfile.tmp", "w")
for i in dirlisting:
    log = open(i, 'r')
    commitFile.write(log.read())
    log.close()
os.execlp("svn", "svn", "commit", "-F", "commitfile.tmp")
```

You'll need to fix the last line to do something that calls tortoise instead though. I have not tested either of these scripts.

Obviously you'd want to clean this up a little bit and make it a bit smarter, but you can see what I'm driving at.

Comment: You don't have to do a commit, if you cancel the commit the log message is retained in TortoiseSVN history. But I don't think that solves the problem (completely) because each history item would need to be combined.

Comment: I was suggesting that you could use it as a place to store notes.

Comment: @Si: I tested vanilla svn, it ignored a svn-commit.tmp that I created and made it's own svn-commit.2.tmp

I've added a script to my answer that might be what he's looking for.

Comment: Absolutely, and I agree that it would work, except that you have to combine the history messages together for your commit.

Comment: Si: See the two scripts I've written. They pull the messages from a directory called logs.

Comment: Nice idea, but wouldn't that record the whole history until it gets cleared? History *isn't* cleared after a commit (unless you do it manually), and I think you really only want the history preserved from the last successful commit.

Comment: Add to the script to clear the logs directory afterwards then I guess? I don't really have the time or the motivation to write this entire thing for him but I'm happy to give a usable framework :) in that case he'd want to use os.system and inspect the return value.

Comment: Yup, that could work Richo. I'd also suggest emailing Stefan and the TorotiseSVN team via their mailing list, as they might consider adding it as a separate feature.

Comment: Thanks, not exactly what I was looking for, but the idea works nicely.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with using a diff tool and reviewing your changes before commit?

If you can't remember the reason for changes, or work them out from the code, then isn't that a clue that you need to commit more often? Commits are cheap and quick, and if the changes are logically related in a revision, it makes reverting and merging (in the future) much easier.

Comment: +1 to this, I commit a lot. I group related changes (and make sure that if changes depend upon one another they're included in a single commit!) but don't see the issue with lots of commits.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting Question.

This answer is probably out of context, but if you are flexible to move towards another version control system, I would suggest moving to [Git](http://git-scm.com/) (allows you to have local commits). I am not saying anything aganist SVN, its great, just that Git might suite you better as per the use case.

Comment: Mercurial (http://mercurial.selenic.com/) does something similar to Git. Local copies with messages associated with them. Then a big push with all of your notes.

Comment: -1 I'm not saying anything against Git, I'm sure it's great, it's just that the question is about SVN ;-)